# Changing size of window when testing Adobe AIR mobile applications

Tags: flash, adobe-air, actionscript

Im making a mobile phone Android application in Flash CS 5.5. I set the width/height of the stage to 480/800 px.

When I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to test run the application I get a window that is 480/800 px. It cannot be resized. I want to change the size of that window WITHOUT changing the stage width/height.

For example if I run the APK on a mobile phone with a 1000x1000 display the flash will scale automatically to fit the 480/800 stage to the 1000x1000 screen.

So it should be possible to change the window size to 1000x1000 without having to change the stage width/height.

But how?

Comment: This is more of a programming question than a user question (although it's both). You might get more answers over on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I would have posted on stackoverflow but they have changed their policy and do no longer support posting questions without creating an account. I do not support this so I have taken refugee on this lovely site instead. Being able to post questions without the hassle of signing up first is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question (or your issue) but I will try to answer that which I think you're asking.

Try setting the `[stage.scaleMode][1]` to `NO_SCALE`. Then, at run-time check the `stageWidth` and `stageHeight` and build your scene based on those values. As a suggestion, when setting the `stage.scaleMode` try setting the align as well to `TOP_LEFT`. Unless the `scaleMode` is set to `no_scale` Flash automatically scales the declared stage dimensions to the dimensions of the container. If the `scaleMode` is set to `no_scale` then the declared dimensions are ignored and the dimensions of the container are used for the stage.